# How to get rid of blue grid in Game in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can i get rid of that blue grid [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cwoa.png) in Unity when starting my game?

Comment: Looks like the tiles are not completely filling the grid -> have transparent borders -> the blue you see is whatever is configured as background in your camera ...

Answer (score 1):

If you adjust the "Pixels Per Unit" on the sprites in your sprite sheet you can eliminate the gaps in your grid. Or you can change the Cell Size and Cell Gap of your grid.